# How can I make the `cmd.exe` window full-screen in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, fullscreen

How can I make the `cmd.exe` window full-screen in Windows 7?

Answer (score 8):

This is a more concise way to perform the steps in @Enrique's answer.  I'm posting this in case the [source](http://www.walkernews.net/2009/11/22/enable-full-screen-command-prompt-window-persistently-in-windows-7/) in his answer disappears.

1. Open a command prompt (cmd.exe)
2. From inside the command prompt window, run *wmic*
3. Right-Click the title bar of the command prompt window and select *Properties*
4. Check *QuickEdit Mode*
5. Exit the command prompt

All subsequent launches of the command prompt will have a horizontal scroll bar and support maximizing the window.

Once these steps have been followed, I'm not sure how to return the command prompt to the original state.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the Windows XP driver of your graphic cards and install it.

You will lose Aero, but `cmd.exe` will be able to enter fullscreen by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Losing Aero will probably be the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found necessary, is increasing the buffer size to a large enough value that it can fill the screen.

- Launch `cmd.exe`
- Click the icon on the top-left corner of the window
- Click `Properties` in the menu
- Click the `Layout` tab
- Set the `Width` and `Height` of Screen Buffer size to a large value (if the value is not large enough, `cmd.exe` will still not go fullscreen; e.g. 300 x 300)
- Set the `Width` and `Height` of Window size to a larger value (e.g. 160 x 55 works fine on a resolution of 1366x768; for higher resolution the value must be larger)
- Now you can click the 'Maximize' icon on the top right corner (or press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>)

You can then re-size the window if you do not want it fullscreen.

Answer (score -2):

Press `Alt + Enter`.

That's it.

Comment: Alt-Enter no loger works in Win7 for console windows.

Comment: It doesnt work in Windows 8 either